# Triggered send not sending email

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, triggered-send, python, marketingcloudapi

I am using Python [Fuel-SDK](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python). I get the following response from triggered send, but the email is not sent

```
Send Status: True
Code: HTTPStatus.OK
Message: OK
Result Count: 1
Results: [(TriggeredSendCreateResult){
   StatusCode = "OK"
   StatusMessage = "Created TriggeredSend"
   OrdinalID = 0
   NewID = 0
 }]
```

My code to send email is as follows:
import FuelSDK

```
# Next, create an instance of the ET_Client class:
myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client(False, False,
                             {"clientid": <clientid>,
                              "clientsecret": <clientsecret>,
                              "authenticationurl": <auth_url>,
                              "useOAuth2Authentication":"True"
                              })
# Send Trigger Email
sendTrig = FuelSDK.ET_TriggeredSend()
sendTrig.auth_stub = myClient
sendTrig.props = {"CustomerKey": "test_trigger"}
sendTrig.subscribers = [{"EmailAddress": <emailaddress>, "SubscriberKey": 10840,}]
sendTrig.attributes = [{'Name':'name','Value':"Priyam Maheshwari"},
                        {'Name':'paper_title_1','Value':"paper title"}]

sendResponse = sendTrig.send()
print('Send Status: ' + str(sendResponse.status))
print('Code: ' + str(sendResponse.code))
print('Message: ' + str(sendResponse.message))
print('Result Count: ' + str(len(sendResponse.results)))
print('Results: ' + str(sendResponse.results))
```

I have checked Triggered sends dashboard in Marketing cloud web UI, and there is nothing in the queue/error. It doesn't look like it even received the request to send email

Comment: I would suggest testing with a sync call to get an error but my guess would be this subscriber is either unsubbed or held

Comment: Of there is an error caused by the email content, eg AMPscript error

Comment: if your api call is going through successfully, there are still quite a few things in that SFMC can stop the send, choice cuts: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332320/email-send-does-not-send-to-everyone-in-data-extension-no-reason-for-exclusion/332329#332329